# How to show three labels and spinner just below my textbox?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I am working with android and I have designed my xml in which I am showing three buttons at the bottom of my screen and also I am showing a textbox (textboxA) at the center of my screen along with three buttons at the bottom of the screen.

Now I would like to show three labels and three spinners just below the `textboxA` Is possible to do? I tried using the below code but some of my labels and spinners are off

```
textboxA

labelA: SpinnerA
labelB: SpinnerB
labelC: SpinnerC
```

Below is my xml layout -

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="ButtonA" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="ButtonB" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="ButtonC" />
</LinearLayout>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="textboxA"
    android:inputType="text" >
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Radius1: " />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edittext"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view_2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Radius2: " />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edittext"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view_3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Radius3: " />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edittext"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Is there anything wrong I am doing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using RelativeLayout you should use toLeftOf or above or below xml properties in the items to define their positions

**Edit:**

Try this layout, obviously you will have to tweek it a bit to fullfil your needs:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="textboxA"
        android:inputType="text" >
    </EditText>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/firstRadius"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edittext" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Radius1: " />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/secondRadius"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/firstRadius" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Radius2: " />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/thirdRadius"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/secondRadius" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Radius3: " />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="ButtonA" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="ButtonB" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="ButtonC" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it is helpful.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Can you provide an example basis on my xml which I can try out. It will help me to understand better.

Comment: Try to copy my suggestion and check out if it is what you was expecting. Obviously is not perfect but it is a starting point for you to achive your goal.